# Agregar ComboBox dentro de ListView

Tags: vb.net, .net, listview, combobox

Quisiera me apoyaran para poder agregar un control ComboBox dentro de un ListView.

En la imagen se aprecia el Listview, quiero agregar un comboBox en la segunda columna por cada ítem que existe en la primera.

[image: ListView]

Answer (score -1):

Existe un artículo de Microsoft donde enseña como hacer paso a paso: [Cómo utilizar un control ComboBox para modificar datos en un control ListView en Visual Basic 2005 o en Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/es-co/help/320342/how-to-use-a-combobox-control-to-edit-data-in-a-listview-control-in-visual-basic-2005-or-in-visual-basic-.net)

La idea es crear un control heredado de `ListView` que tendrá su evento `MouseUp` y que incluirá un contenedor de controles, para este caso un `ComboBox` donde jugarás con su propiedad `Visible` en sus eventos `SelectedValueChanged`, `KeyPress` y `Leave`.

**Creación de Control de Usuario**
*Crea un proyecto de Biblioteca de Windows que contenga dicho control para que luego sea referenciado en tu formulario*.

```
Imports SystemImports System.Collections
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MyListView
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ListView

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()        
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    End Sub

    Private Const WM_HSCROLL As Integer = &H114
    Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef msg As Message)
        If ((msg.Msg = WM_VSCROLL) Or (msg.Msg = WM_HSCROLL)) Then
            Me.Focus()
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(msg)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Aplicación para Windows** *Tendrá tu formulario donde contendrá los controles necesarios y definirás los eventos del control `MyListView` (control heredado de `ListView`) y del `Combobox`.*

En tu formulario agregas un control `Combobox` (cambiar nombre a *cbListViewComboy*) con su propiedad `Visible` en `False`.

Agregas una variable global en tu formulario:

```
Private lvItem As ListViewItem
```

En el evento `Load` del formulario agregas:

```
Me.cbListViewCombo.Items.Add("NC")
Me.cbListViewCombo.Items.Add("WA")    

Me.MyListView1.View = View.Details
Me.MyListView1.FullRowSelect = True    

Dim columnheader As ColumnHeader
Dim lviewitem As ListViewItem    

lviewitem = New ListViewItem("NC")
lviewitem.SubItems.Add("North Carolina")
Me.MyListView1.Items.Add(lviewitem)

lviewitem = New ListViewItem("WA")
lviewitem.SubItems.Add("Washington")
Me.MyListView1.Items.Add(lviewitem)    

columnheader = New ColumnHeader()
columnheader.Text = "State Abbr."
Me.MyListView1.Columns.Add(columnheader)

columnheader = New ColumnHeader()
columnheader.Text = "State"
Me.MyListView1.Columns.Add(columnheader)    

Dim ch As ColumnHeader

For Each ch In Me.MyListView1.Columns
   ch.Width = -2
Next
```

Agregas en el evento `SelectedValueChanged` del `ComboBox`

```
lvItem.Text = Me.cbListViewCombo.Text
Me.cbListViewCombo.Visible = False
```

Agregas en el evento `Leave` del `ComboBox`

```
lvItem.Text = Me.cbListViewCombo.Text
Me.cbListViewCombo.Visible = False
```

Agregas en el evento `KeyPress` del `ComboBox`

```
Select Case (e.KeyChar)
   Case ChrW(CType(Keys.Escape, Integer))
      Me.cbListViewCombo.Text = lvItem.Text
      Me.cbListViewCombo.Visible = False

   Case ChrW(CType(Keys.Enter, Integer))
      Me.cbListViewCombo.Visible = False
End Select
```

Y para finalizar, agregas en el evento `MouseUp` del `myListView1`

```
lvItem = Me.MyListView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)

If Not (lvItem Is Nothing) Then
   Dim ClickedItem As Rectangle = lvItem.Bounds

   If ((ClickedItem.Left + Me.MyListView1.Columns(0).Width) < 0) Then
      Return
   ElseIf (ClickedItem.Left < 0) Then
      If ((ClickedItem.Left + Me.MyListView1.Columns(0).Width) > Me.MyListView1.Width) Then                   
         ClickedItem.Width = Me.MyListView1.Width
         ClickedItem.X = 0
      Else
         ClickedItem.Width = Me.MyListView1.Columns(0).Width + ClickedItem.Left
         ClickedItem.X = 2
      End If

   ElseIf (Me.MyListView1.Columns(0).Width > Me.MyListView1.Width) Then
      ClickedItem.Width = Me.MyListView1.Width

   Else
      ClickedItem.Width = Me.MyListView1.Columns(0).Width
      ClickedItem.X = 2
   End If

   ClickedItem.Y += Me.MyListView1.Top
   ClickedItem.X += Me.MyListView1.Left

   Me.cbListViewCombo.Bounds = ClickedItem

   Me.cbListViewCombo.Text = lvItem.Text

   Me.cbListViewCombo.Visible = True
   Me.cbListViewCombo.BringToFront()
   Me.cbListViewCombo.Focus()
End If
```

- [Tutorial: Crear un control de formularios Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/35ea88wb(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

En caso se necesite para `C#`, también existe un artículo: [Cómo utilizar un control ComboBox para modificar datos en un control ListView en Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/320344/how-to-use-a-combobox-control-to-edit-data-in-a-listview-control-in-visual-c)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/30525)

Comment: @Awes0meM4n acostumbrándome a las contradictorias de SO y SOes al momento de responder una pregunta. Agregado el código fuente.